# Check if module loaded in shell or imported in a script

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to check if a certain module is being imported from the interactive shell or being imported from a script/another module in Python? I am working on a module and need different behavior based on the it being used from the shell or used in a script (the actions to take, i.e. closing some midi ports etc. need this information).

Comment: Yes I meant using the module itself directly from the interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python inserts an empty `__main__` module in `sys.modules` at interpreter startup, and populates it by running [top-level code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#what-is-the-top-level-code-environment).

In the case of an interactive session, the the `__main__` scope does not contain a `__file__` attribute. This can be used to detect a REPL.

```
import __main__
try:
    __main__.__file__
except AttributeError:
    print("interactive")
else:
    print("non-interactive")
```